# Manipulating an Array into a New Array

Tags: java, arrays, variables, methods

I am trying to write a method that takes an array, and adds adjacent cells together to produce a new array. It's easier to explain with examples:

{11, 4, 3, 18, 23, 9} --> {15, 21, 32}

{5, 5, 21, 13, 1} --> {10, 34}   (the sixth cell is just ignored)

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] a) {
    int[] b = new int[a.length / 2];
    for (int j = 0 ; j < (a.length - 1) ; j+2) {    //goes thru original array
        for (int i = 0 ; i < b.length ; i++) {      //populates new array
            b[i] = a[j] + a[j+1];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

I figured this required using nested for-loops, the first one to go thru the original array, and the second one to populate the new array. I know that the j+2 in the first for-loop is syntactically incorrect, but I cannot figure out another way to accomplish the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem #1: The third expression in a `for` usually needs to be something that modifies the index.  `j+2` by itself doesn't do that; `j = j + 2` would.  (Or `j += 2`.)

Problem #2: You do not want a nested `for` loop.  What this does is: first it sets `j` to 0 and lets `i` go through the whole `b` array.  Then it increments `j` (after you fix the first problem) and lets `i` go through the whole `b` array again.  This isn't what you want; you want them to be increased in parallel.

One way is just to declare `i` as a variable outside the loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j += 2) {
     b[i++] = a[j] + a[j + 1];
}
```

making sure the body of the loop increments `i`.  Or, you can get fancy:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < a.length - 1; i++, j += 2) {
    b[i] = a[j] + a[j + 1];
}
```

and let the `for` increment both indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use two loops. Just keep a counter (outputIndex) that represents your position in the output array, and increment it each time after you use it:

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] a) {
    int[] b = new int[a.length / 2];
    int outputIndex = 0;
    for (int j = 1 ; j < a.length ; j+=2) {    //goes thru original array
        b[outputIndex++] = a[j - 1] + a[j];
    }
    return b;
}
```

Also, I started the loop at j = 1, so that it handles the case where you are missing the last item to be added. Just remember that the two items you are adding are at [j-1] and [j], not [j] and [j+1].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant `j=j+2`, not just `j+2`?

In fact, this can be done with one `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length - oldArray.length % 2; i+=2) {
    newArray[i/2] = oldArray[i] + oldArray[i+1]
}
```

The `i < oldArray.length - oldArray.length % 2` ensures that for an odd array, the last element is ignored.